# How to turn off supports in Z-Suite (Zortrax slicing software)

Tags: software

I would like to print a model without supports on the Zortrax M200. To do this it is mandatory to use the proprietory Z-Suite slicer. I am certain that at some point I found an option to turn off support struts (I specifically remember the text "(not recommended)" appearing in the UI somewhere), but it seems not to be there now. Is my memory playing tricks on me, or is there a way to enable a "no supports" option in Z-Suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer for myself by playing around a bit more. It seems that in selecting the "support angle", a higher angle means *more* supports. This was confusing me, because I had assumed "support angle" meant the maximum angle of overhang before a support would be generated. I guess it does actually mean that, but it counts 90º rather than 0º as vertical. In any case, supports are turned off simply by changing it to 0, in which case the text "not recommended" does indeed appear.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for posting the answer, made my life real easy. Have a good one!